# Unable to execute integration tests

Tags: testing, integration-testing, nearprotocol, decentralized-applications

Getting this error when trying to execute GuestBook tutorial project locally. When executed thru GitPod everything works fine, tho.

```
Rejected promise returned by test. Reason:

  Error (TypedError) {
    context: undefined,
    type: 'RetriesExceeded',
    message: 'Exceeded 10 attempts for http://localhost:8972.',
  }
```

I tried to debug it. Found out that the test breaks on these lines:

```
const alice = await root.createSubAccount("alice", {
    initialBalance: NEAR.parse("30 N").toJSON(),
  });
  const contract = await root.createSubAccount("contract", {
    initialBalance: NEAR.parse("30 N").toJSON(),
  });
```